# Is it possible to call "level all" through vba in ms-project?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am using Microsoft Project 2010 professional and i want to know if it is possible to :
**The Question**

1. Use visual basic to call the "Level All" function under the resource tab.

**Why would i want that?**

I want to do this because we are using various "cadence" in our project. So the same array of tasks might be done in 4 days, or 10 days. Now when there is such a change in "cadence" we will have to increase/decrease the number of employees working on the day/night shifts and reassign tasks to wether day or night shift. This task has to be done manually. And I obviously want to automate it.

So i want to address overallocated tasks and "past deadline" errors. Hence the need to get the indicators columns value.

**Project settings**
I am using 2 calendars:

- "DayShift" everyday from 6:30 AM to 2:30 PM
- "AfterDayBeforeNight" everyday from 2:30 PM to 10:30 PM

Assigned to two resource:
[image]

**The code:**

```
Dim t As Task       
For Each t In Application.ActiveProject.Tasks
Dim success As Boolean
Dim r As Resource    
success = Application.SelectRow(t.ID, False)    
If success Then
Dim posAJ As Integer
Dim posAS As Integer        
posAJ = InStr(t.ResourceNames, "A-J")
posAS = InStr(t.ResourceNames, "A-S")
If posAJ <> 0 Then
Font32Ex CellColor:=62207
End If
If posAS <> 0 Then
Font32Ex CellColor:=32207
End If
Dim warn As String
warn = t.Warning
End If
Next
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q2: You can call from VBA

```
LevelNow All:=True
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195121(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for ! I'll edit my question in order to mark your answer as "THE" answer and i'll ask the first one on a separated thread.